# Apex Trigger : Insert record on another object on "afterInsert" event

Tags: apex, trigger

A fresher question.

We have a custom object named "CaseLogger".

CaseLogger does not have any custom fields.

Whenever a new Case is created, a CaseLogger record will be created with it's "Name" field being a concatenation of "Case Id + Case Origin".

For example let's think of a scenario in which Case C is created. Its Origin is "Email" and its Id is "19191".

Then a new `CaseLogger` record will be created as follows

`CaseLogger.Name = 19191Email`

I wrote the following trigger.

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case ( after insert)
{

    List<CaseLogger__c> l = null;

    for(Case c : Trigger.new)
    {
        //I am stuck here 
    }

    insert l;       
}
```

I know the code that I wrote is not much.

1. I know that we always have to "bulkify" and should use DML wisely.
2. So If **1** is to be honored, then I assume that Case records present in Trigger.new are to be stored in a collection.
3. But I am unable to find a method in List class that can allow me to create CaseLogger list entries with only data given for one of its fields

For example something like

```
l (the collection from the above code snippet)

l.Name.add(c.id+c.Origin)
```

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your above snippet and example, but they are easy to fix.

First you need to initialise your `List`.

```
List<CaseLogger__c> l = new List<CaseLogger__c>();
```

The `add()` method on a `List<CaseLogger__c>` will take a `CaseLogger__c` as its parameter:

```
l.add(new CaseLogger__c(Name = c.Id + c.Origin));
```

I'd also advise that you give `l` a more descriptive name.

Putting that all together you get:

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case ( after insert)
{
    List<CaseLogger__c> loggers = new List<CaseLogger__c>();

    for(Case c : Trigger.new)
    {
        loggers.add(new CaseLogger__c(Name = c.Id + c.Origin));
    }

    insert loggers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

****Ans: we want to store the data of one object to another object.****

1. Firstly i have created the two object like as Object1__c and Object2__c.
2. We want to store the data of one table(Object1__c) to another table(Object2__c)
3. Name field is common in both the Object .

.

```
trigger InsertObject2 on Object1__c (after insert) 
{
/* create the list of second object in which i will store the data of first object.*/

    List<Object2__c> obj2=new List<Object2__c>();

/*using loop store the data one by one into variable obj1 */

    for(Object1__c obj1:Trigger.New)
    {
        obj2.add(new Object2__c(name=obj1.name));/*add the name data of Object1__c table into Object2__c table */

    }
    insert obj2;
}
```

Thanks
Mukesh Yadav